# How can I get the middle point between two points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am working with a centreline of equidistant points. I want middle points of those points. 
For example, if the distance between each of the points is 24.99m. I want to locate the exact middle point at 12.495m. How can I do that with ArcMap tools, not Python?  This is a shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how things work here.  The midpoint between two points always occurs at {(p1x+p2x)*0.5, p1y+p2y)*0.5 }, but getting to that result without Python might prove challenging.  Please **edit** your question to clarify what you mean by "ArcMap tools".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combined the two points of which you want middle points into a multipoint,then you can use the tool  "FeatureToPoint".It will create  new point based on each multipoint ,the new point is just the centre point of the two original points.The tool "FeatureToPoint" is located at "Data management tool——Feature".The version of ArcGIS is 10.X.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to locate the midpoint interactively, there is a midpoint tool that can be used while editing. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/creating-a-point-or-vertex-at-the-midpoint-of-two-locations.htm

Comment: I have already tried to do this way, but it's manual. And I have 360 points and have to find the midpoints between each. It's tedious. So, wanna know something automatic/using tool.